# GetModuleFileName() not giving the correct path of DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

I'm using two directories to run the application, I have placed the EXE file in one directory and DLLs in another; after executing the EXE, I want to load another DLL at run time, so I'm using `GetModuleFileName()` to get the working DLL path to load another DLL from the same directory. However, it's returning the executable directory path instead of the DLL's path, so I'm not able to load another DLL.

Comment: It will return the path you want if you pass the module handle of the DLL. It would be better for you to use side by side assemblies and let the loader take care of everything. Or even just put the DLLs in the same directory as the executable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea):

> A handle to the loaded module whose path is being requested. If this parameter is **NULL**, **GetModuleFileName** retrieves the path of the executable file of the current process.

So make sure you passed the instance of the `DLL` correctly.

I create a sample to test:

```
char result[MAX_PATH];
HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary("D:\\test\\Dll1.dll");
GetModuleFileNameA(hDLL, result, MAX_PATH);
```

It works for me:

[image]

Comment: It's working when I hardcoded the path, but I need to get the path at run time.
I have written the same logic for other applications, that were working as expected.

Comment: @Vipin `GetModuleFileName` works correctly. The problem is either in your expectation, or your code. If you won't show your code then you'll have to solve the problem by yourself. I suggest that you read this answer again, more carefully. Note how the code calls `GetModuleFileName` and obtains the path of the module, at runtime. Nowhere in this code is anything hard coded into `result`.

Comment: @Vipin If it works when you hardcoded the path.Maybe there is a problem with other parts of your code snippets, maybe you can show your code so that we can find the problem.

Comment: Thanks all, now it's working as expected, I was getting NULL that's why it's getting the exe path instead dll path.

Comment: If this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.